# Python pandas dataframe restriction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
series   outcome
1          T
1          F
1          T
2          T
2          F
3          T
4          F
4          T
5          F
```

I have a data frame looking something like this and I  am trying to look at the proportion of T on the outcome for each series. However I do not understand why i m not being able to make it work

```
series = np.unique(series)
count = 0 
pcorrect = np.zeros(len(nseries))
for s in nseries:
   if data.loc[data['series'] == s]:
       outcome_count = data['outcome'].value_counts()
       nstarted_trials = outcome_count['T'] + outcome_count[F'] 
       pcorrect[count]= outcome_count['T'] / nstarted_trials
    count +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.series,df.outcome,margins = True)
Out[698]: 
outcome  F  T  All
series            
1        1  2    3
2        1  1    2
3        0  1    1
4        1  1    2
5        1  0    1
All      4  5    9
```

If need percentage

```
pd.crosstab(df.series,df.outcome,margins = True, normalize=True)
Out[699]: 
outcome         F         T       All
series                               
1        0.111111  0.222222  0.333333
2        0.111111  0.111111  0.222222
3        0.000000  0.111111  0.111111
4        0.111111  0.111111  0.222222
5        0.111111  0.000000  0.111111
All      0.444444  0.555556  1.000000
```